# NCR Ranger Safehouse - I can't get in

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've heard that in the NCR Ranger Safehouse in FO:NV (near Black Mountain) there is some nice gear to be found.

I have a positive reputation with the NCR, and I also have the NCR Safehouse key from Col. James Hsu. But, the door to the safe-house still says "Requires Key".

I did my research and found this on the [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/NCR_Ranger_safehouse#Bugs):

> After discovering the location, an NCR Sergeant and an NCR soldier may come and talk to you. Afterward, when fast-travelling to the NCR Ranger Safehouse, the door can be locked with no option to do anything, and the rocks along the path will not be solid.

This does not seem to be the case, though. No NCR sergeant or soldier talked to me while I approached the entrance, and the rocks are still solid. What's the problem?

Comment: The prerequisite for the key is "after gaining a reputation of Liked with the New California Republic (NCR)." Don't know if that would cause a problem if it changed. Is your rep still at least 'Liked'?

Comment: @DCShannon My rep is "Smiling Troublemaker", which I believe is a "Liked" fame and "Shunned" infamy.

Comment: I can't find anything definitive on the internets, but my guess is that there's a problem with your infamy. To test this, I would need to have a character that is like or better, without infamy. Make a savepoint (A), get the key and confirm I can enter the safehouse, then load A, get some infamy, go get the key and see if I can get in the safehouse.

Comment: Do you know if you were already at Smiling Troublemaker when you got the key?

Comment: Probably. Since I've sided with the NCR and done all main NCR quests I'm at least liked. But I chose to get into the Strip through completing a quest for The King, which required me to kill NCR. So yes, I was most likely Smiling Troublemaker when I got the key.

Comment: I was neutral with the NCR when I entered the safehouse (because of the faction armor rep glitch. As long as you have the key you can enter.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a glitch that hasn't been recorded on the wikia.

Because of your liked reputation with the NCR and the key you received from Col. Hsu you should be able to access the NCR Ranger Safehouse. You should check your keyring to see if the NCR Safehouse Key has been properly added to your inventory; the keyring is in your Pipboy's MISC tab.

If, due to a bug, you never received your key to the NCR Safehouse you can add it to your inventory using this console command `player.additem 00162998 1`.

If you do have the Safehouse key and you still can't open the door use the console command `unlock`, click on the door, and press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of reputation with the NCR not discovery. You need not discover it at all. They will find you and tell you the location on your pipboy

Comment: Not correct, you have to reach a certain reputation and then actually talk to the Colonel in Camp McCarren

Answer (score -3):

if you killed NCR members to get into the strip, this is not necessary, you can simply say you will sort it out for the king and use certain skills to make them withdraw, but you must talk to Julie Farkas, and then the NCR person in the hand out area about the attempt to talk about serving locals if you mention Julie.
This will keep you from smiling troublemaker if that is the problem

Comment: This answer has no relevance to the question whatsoever.